# Android app freeze when keyboard is shown after using NotificationCenter

Tags: delphi, push-notification, keyboard, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a huge app made on Delphi (Berlin) and now I got an issue that I cannot solve:

- After presenting a simple notification using the TNotificationCenter the app continues to work fine, everything is OK, but when the user taps an Edit the app freezes right after the keyboard is shown, the keyboard still working but the app is frozen. Or, if the user had opened the keyboard on any Edit before and the app present a notification, the app freezes before the notification is shown.

The only way I found to prevent this is commenting the line:

```
NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(MyNotification);
```

So the only solution for my app is remove all notifications or re-made on another development platform?

Anyone got a hint?

Edit:

So, the Native Edit doesn't solve my problem, actually it make the app freeze right after the notification is shown event without tapping the Edit.

Then, I removed all main Form.OnShow events, all main Form.OnVirtualKeyBoardHidden and main Form.OnVirtualKeyBoardShown events, all main Form.KeyUp events, all kind of events from a specific Edit and tried it. App still freezing;

The 8 sec Timer that presents the Notification:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  I,Brk:integer;
  RaioCemMetros:string;
  RaioMetrosF:double;
  Notif:boolean;
  aDay: TDateTime;
  aaStart,aaFinish: TTime;
  DayOk:boolean;
  HoraStart,MinStart,HoraFim,MinFim:string;
  Dia,Mes,Ano:string;
  Tipo: string;
  Dayofwk: integer;
  Navig:string;
begin
Label1.Text := '1 '+DownloadedAlerts.Text;
Brk := 0;
Notif := False;
if ((CityBackground.Tag = 0) and (IdDownloadClient.Tag = 0) and     (Form58.Image1.Tag = 0) and (Form64.Image1.Tag = 0) and (TabControl1.TabIndex =     0) and (DownloadedAlerts.Text <> '') and (LastNotifON = False) and (NotifOn))             then
  begin
Label1.Text := '2';
  LatS := StringReplace(lat,'.',',',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  LongS := StringReplace(long,'.',',',[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  LatF := StrToFloat(LatS);
  LongF := StrToFloat(LongS);

  for I := 0 to DownloadedAlerts.Count-1 do
  begin
    Brk := I;
    EventLatURL := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],2,16);
    EventLongURL := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],19,16);
    EventLatS := StringReplace(EventLatURL,'.',',',[rfReplaceAll,     rfIgnoreCase]);
    EventLongS := StringReplace(EventLongURL,'.',',',[rfReplaceAll,     rfIgnoreCase]);
    EventLatF := StrToFloat(EventLatS);
    EventLongF := StrToFloat(EventLongS);
    DistanciaV := abs(LatF-EventLatF);
    DistanciaH := abs(LongF-EventLongF);

    distanciaGPS := sqrt(sqr(DistanciaV) + sqr(DistanciaH));
    distanciaMETROS := distanciaGPS*(111120*0.946);

    RaioCemMetros := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],55,4);
    RaioMetrosF := 100*StrToFloat(RaioCemMetros);

    if RaioMetrosF >= distanciaMETROS then
    begin
    Label1.Text := '3';
    DayOk := False;
    Dayofwk := DayOfTheWeek(Now);
      case Dayofwk of
        7: if (ansipos('11111111',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;     // Domingo
        1: if (ansipos('22222222',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
        2: if (ansipos('33333333',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
        3: if (ansipos('44444444',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
        4: if (ansipos('55555555',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
        5: if (ansipos('66666666',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
        6: if (ansipos('77777777',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
      end;

      if (ansipos('99999999',DownloadedAlerts[I]) > 0) then DayOk := True;
      if ((DayOk = False) and (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('11111111') = False)     and (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('22222222') = False) and
       (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('33333333') = False) and     (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('44444444') = False) and
        (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('55555555') = False) and     (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('66666666') = False) and
         (DownloadedAlerts[I].Contains('77777777') = False)) then
      begin
         Dia := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],36,2);
         Mes := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],38,2);
         Ano := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],40,4);
         aDay := StrToDate(Dia+'/'+Mes+'/'+Ano);
         if aDay = Today then DayOk := True;
      end;
      if DayOk then
      begin
        HoraStart := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],45,2);
        MinStart := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],47,2);
        HoraFim := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],50,2);
        MinFim := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],52,2);

        aaStart:= StrToTime(HoraStart+':'+MinStart+':00');
        aaFinish := StrToTime(HoraFim+':'+MinFim+':59');

        if (TimeInRange(Now,aaStart,aaFinish)) = True then
        begin
        Label1.Text := '4';
          Tipo := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],1,1);
          Navig := Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],35,1);
          Application.ProcessMessages;
          Notificationn := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
          try
            if ((Tipo <> 'p') and (Tipo <> 'c')) then
            begin
              LastNotifOn := True;
              LastNotifLat := EventLatS;
              LastNotifLong := EventLongS;
              Label6.Text :=     Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],60,ansipos('|',DownloadedAlerts[I])-60);
              if distanciaMETROS >= 1000 then Label7.Text :=     FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de distância agora' else
              Label7.Text := FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS,1))+' metros de     distância agora';
              Label9.Text := 'Alerta às '+IntToStr(HourOfTheDay(Now))+'h     '+IntToStr(MinuteOfTheHour(Now))+'m';
              Label10.Text :=     Copy(DownloadedAlerts[I],ansipos('|',DownloadedAlerts[I])+1,DownloadedAlerts[I].    Length-ansipos('|',DownloadedAlerts[I]));
              RoundRect1.Visible := True;
              RoundRect1.Opacity := 1.0;
              Rectangle5.Visible := True;
              Rectangle5.Opacity := 1.0;
            end;
            Notif := True;
            Image2.Visible := True;
            Label3.Visible := True;
            Button8.Visible := True;
            Notificationn.Name := 'Name';
            if Tipo = 'h' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Check-out';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Hotel há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if ((Tipo = 'n') and (Parado)) then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Área';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Área com chamados reduzidos';  //     Primeira mensagem, que some em 1 segundo
            end else
            if Tipo = 'o' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Hospital';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Hospital há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'b' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Balada';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Saída de balada há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'f' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Partida';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Saída de torcedores há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'i' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Igreja';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Missa próxima do fim há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS,1))+' metros de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 's' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Show';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Show de música há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'e' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Evento';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Evento há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'm' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Motorista Ajudante';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Mensagem do Motorista Ajudante';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'u' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Alerta de Alunos';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Saída de alunos há menos de     '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS/1000,-1))+' km de você';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'p' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Posto em promoção';
            Notificationn.Name := 'Promocao';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Combustível em promoção reportado por um     motorista há '+FloatToStr(RoundTo(distanciaMETROS,1))+' metros de você.';
            end else
            if Tipo = 'c' then begin
            Notificationn.Title := 'Chamado suspeito!';
            Notificationn.Name := 'Chamado';
            Notificationn.AlertBody := 'Solicitação suspeita foi reportada por     um motorista nesta região.';
            end;
            if Navig = '6' then begin
            Image2.Visible := False;
            Label3.Visible := False;
            Button8.Visible := False;
            end;
            Label1.Text := '5';
            Notificationn.EnableSound := False;
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            Label1.Text := '6';
            NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(Notificationn);  // <<< Removing this line solves everything, but no Android notification is sent to the     user
            Label1.Text := '7';
            if NotifAudio = True then begin
              MediaPlayer1.FileName := (TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim +     'iclassy.mp3');
              MediaPlayer1.Play;
            end;
          finally
          Label1.Text := '8';
            Notificationn.DisposeOf;
            Label1.Text := '9';
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  if Notif = True then Break;
  end;
   if Notif = True then
    begin
   Timer3.Tag := 0;
try
Label1.Text := '10';
   DownloadedAlerts.Delete(Brk);
   Label1.Text := '11';
except
Label1.Text := 'Except';
end;
    end else Timer3.Tag := 1;
   if ((Tipo = 'p') or (Tipo = 'c')) then
   begin
     LastNotifON := False;
     Timer3.Tag := 1;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

All "Label1.Text := 'XX'" is for debugging purposes.

Anyone had that issue with TNotificationCenter before?

PS: Embarcadero Delphi Berlin / Android platform

PS2: AndroidManifest http://txt.do/dk987

PS3: The notification works fine [Screenshot](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HwKTDqk3dMQLCumwTtzMy5_esRfUMY0zNQQaY582WIqbiw_vr4yOrQPgBlCmuDjNgx8=h900-rw)

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock happening somewhere.

Comment: Some hints about when asking a question, regardless of the problem: Please indicate what version of Delphi you're using, and what platform you're targeting. For this question, please indicate whether you're doing any handling when the VK is shown/hidden. I also suggest attempting to construct a reproducible test case.

Comment: Can you try to use instead an native Tandroid Edit (like this one you can found here: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/) and see if the app is still freezing ?

Comment: I'll try it and I will post the results, thanks.